# how RMI work with out stub

Tags: java, rmi

can anybody explain how following rmi code work without stub

```
ReceiveMessageInterface.java

import java.rmi.*;

public interface ReceiveMessageInterface extends Remote{

  void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException;

}
```

RmiServer.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RmiServer extends 
  java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements ReceiveMessageInterface{
  String address;
  Registry registry; 

  public void receiveMessage(String x) throws RemoteException{
  System.out.println(x);
  }

  public RmiServer() throws RemoteException{
  try{  
  address = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("can't get inet address.");
  }
  int port=3232; 
  System.out.println("this address=" + address +  ",port=" + port);
  try{
  registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
  registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
  }
  catch(RemoteException e){
  System.out.println("remote exception"+ e);
  }
  }
  static public void main(String args[]){
  try{
  RmiServer server = new RmiServer();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
  }
  }
}
```

RMIClient.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RmiClient{
  static public void main(String args[]){
  ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
  Registry registry;
  String serverAddress=args[0];
  String serverPort=args[1];
  String text=args[2];
  System.out.println
   ("sending " + text + " to " +serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
  try{
  registry=LocateRegistry.getRegistry
  (serverAddress,(new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
  rmiServer=(ReceiveMessageInterface)(registry.lookup("rmiServer"));
  // call the remote method
  rmiServer.receiveMessage(text);
  }
  catch(RemoteException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(NotBoundException e){
  System.err.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note for your next questions: Please use some code indenting to make it more readable. Most IDEs (and some other editors, too) have a feature to automate indenting.

Answer (score 0):

Uses `java.reflect.Proxy` to synthesize an implementation of the interface in runtime

Comment: yes.   As much as i remember you have to do some access policy configuration, but was long time ago i've done it ... sorry

Comment: Access policy configuration isn't required to use dynamic stubs.

Comment: And neither is java.lang.reflect.Proxy. RMI already does this for you. -1

Comment: @EJP read the question carefully. It asks HOW does the thing work. I have answered that. Your comment is redundant (on both points)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is supply a port number parameter, even 0, when constructing or exporting. Just add super(0) in the constructor in the code above.